# WAL level not sufficient for making an online backup

Tags: postgresql, streaming, replication, wal

I have tried to do database replication in linux 7.0 red hat using postgresql.

I refered this URL for Confuring http://blog.terminal.com/postgresql-replication-and-backup-methods/ I completed the the steps upto this step

> 5. Configuring the slave server

but the step

> 6. Initial replication

when I executed this command in Master

```
-bash-4.2$ psql -c "select pg_start_backup('initial_backup');"
```

I got Error Like this

```
ERROR:  WAL level not sufficient for making an online backup
HINT:  wal_level must be set to "archive" or "hot_standby" at server start.
```

So kindly let me know where we are wrong.

Answer (score 0):

On your master PostgreSQL server's configuration file `<PG_DATA>/postgresql.conf` there is parameter called `wal_level` it should be set to either `"archive"` or `"hot_standby"`

Both said to postgres to keep WAL segmetnts for replication server. The difference between the two is rather simple:

- `"hot_standby"` means that your replication server will allow connections for `SELECT` statements
- `"archive"` means you don't want that possibility.

More to read in [this tutorial on streaming replication](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Streaming_Replication)
Also keep in mind that change of `wal_level` property needs server restart to take an effect.

Comment: Note for future users, that from PostgreSQL 9.6 on, `archive` and `hot_standby` have been deprecated and replaced with the new setting `replica`. These are still accepted but mapped to `replica`.